# Referencing a XML database file

Tags: xml, database, xpath, xsd

### The problem

Let's say we have some data in an XML file, e.g. a record of people's names:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<persons>
     <person name="Alice" />
     <person name="Bob" />
</persons>
```

This data is to be thought of as a *static* database that we don't want to change.

Now we want to attach to each item (here: person) an attribute. For example, we could store whether we have met this person before. Of course, you could do something like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<persons>
     <person name="Alice" met="true" />
     <person name="Bob" met="false" />
</persons>
```

However, this changes the original file. We want a second file that references the main database and extends it with the additional attribute.

I'm looking for an elegant, conceptually satisfying (or even standard?) way of implementing this, not just anything that works. The above is only a simplified example.

Essentially, the question is how to store additional attributes for an existing external XML database that we do not want to change directly.

### Possible approaches

So far, there are two options that I can think of:

1. The naive way: Assign UUIDs and use them to reference the original data:

   ```
   <!-- Main file -->
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
   <persons>
        <person name="Alice" id="1234" />
        <person name="Bob" id="1235" />
   </persons>

   <!-- Additional data -->
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
   <attributes>
        <attr id="1234" met="true" />
        <attr id="1235" met="false" />
   </attributes>
   ```
2. Save XPath references to the original data in the 'attributes' file. Does this make sense How could this be done?

Further, better proposals are welcome.

Comment: What's the rationale for this? Updating the data is not a lossy operation so you can always recover the original document if you know what was there.  Or you could just copy the original file.

Comment: The point is that I want to sensibly reference existing data. (Of course, in this short example, copy etc. wouldn't be a problem.) I am looking for a conceptually nice way of doing this.

Comment: The best approach is the one you have started working on.

Comment: @Will Which one? ;-)

Comment: The one that's easy to understand and simple to implement, probably.  But isn't that everything?

Comment: Ok. Unique ids really are easy.

Comment: But I don't like the way it's referenced in the second file. It should be transparent how to get to the original data.

Comment: Use the first approach, with UUIDs and be done. For an effective XPath solution, each XPath would have to contain a key (UUID or name) or record number, it's more more explicit to just have it spelled out in the file.

Comment: RE: "How to get to the original data", you might want to "include" the attributes in the original data with DTD ENTITY similar to the example shown here http://xml.silmaril.ie/includes.html

Comment: i think the xpath idea is the better, cleaner approach. unique ids are annoying to maintain (and verify). if you have 10000 records in your example, then you're going to hit a collision. and if you generate them randomly, you have to make sure you don't collide with an existing record.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if you don't want to modify the original database xml, then forcing a unique id on the original data would require that you do exactly what you don't want to do. however, the xpath idea would require more effort for addressing deeply nested elements.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<persons>
     <person name="Alice" />
     <person name="Bob" />
</persons>
```

is a simple example, where you could then append via

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<attributes>
     <attr path="/persons/person[@name='Alice']" met="true" />
     <attr path="/persons/person[@name='Bob']" met="false" />
</attributes>
```

this is pretty elegant, in that you can glob some values however you want.

given a somewhat more complex example,

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<service-calls>
  <companyA>
    <floor num="1">
      <error type="bsod" cause="unknown" />
    </floor>
    <floor num="1">
      <error type="bsod" cause="unknown" />
    </floor>
    <floor num="3">
      <error type="bsod" cause="unknown" />
    </floor>
  </companyA>
  <companyB>
    <floor num="2">
      <error type="bsod" cause="unknown" />
    </floor>
    <floor num="4">
      <error type="bsod" cause="unknown" />
    </floor>
    <floor num="4">
      <error type="bsod" cause="unknown" />
    </floor>
  </companyB>
</service-calls>
```

it would be obnoxious to go through and add a unique id to each of those. especially when all you want is to update the cause, and attach a "status" attribute. xpath again! for these, you were able to get to the first floor tickets in company A, and the fourth floor tickets in company B (for whatever reason).

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<attributes>
     <attr path="/service-calls/companyA/floor[@num='1']/error" status="fixed" 
         cause="user clicked malformed attachment" />
     <attr path="/service-calls/companyB/floor[@num='4']/error" status="replaced computer" 
         cause="malware worm" />
</attributes>
```

either way, that seems to be the most elegant method.

if you wanted to attach notes to the floor, you could do that, too:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<attributes>
     <attr path="/service-calls/companyA/floor[@num='1']" type="developers who cause trouble" /> 
     <attr path="/service-calls/companyB/floor[@num='4']" type="accounting" />
</attributes>
```